# Unity 2D games, I have troubles with 2D collliders

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-3.0, game-physics

I have a lot of problems with some 2D colliders.
In the past, they work, but now they are horrible:))
I already try with Kinematics, OnCollision2DEnter, OnTriggerEnter etc.
The objects are already on the same layer, the same position on the Z-axis, they interact with each other but my game can't detect the collisions.
The rigidbody and collider don't have material but the objects have skins [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3rxj.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcK82.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've realized that the gravity scale of your ground object is above 1. You can make it 0 so it does not get affected by gravity. Gravity Scale is on your ground object's Rigidbody2D component right below angular drag. Although I could be wrong since what kind of collisions you are expecting and your movement code, that should help resolve your problems.